# Modify Thymleaf template without having to do a server restart

Tags: jetty, frontend, thymeleaf

This is a pretty basic question but I can't seem to find it anywhere.  Is there a way to make changes to a thymeleaf template such that after a change has been made a simple browser refresh will reflect my changes?

I am currently using jetty and was wondering if this behavior could be replicated to how express + jade behaves.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the Thymeleaf template resolver is configured as follows:

```
<bean class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
  <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Ideally you should do this on a per-environment basis so that local changes are reflected immediately in the browser during development but templates are cached on production for the best possible performance.

Comment: No luck.  I am doing just that in the ServletContextTemplateResolver bean of my spring project:

     @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver servletContextTemplateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        servletContextTemplateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return servletContextTemplateResolver;
    }

Comment: Interesting. Take a look at my [sample project on Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-jasper).  If you change any of the files under `src/main/webapp/page` or `src/main/webapp/layout` you can see the changes instantly in the browser.  You can tinker around with this sample by replacing the XML based configuration with Java based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `FileTemplateResolver` in order to make thymeleaf look for templates under `mytemplates/` folder, which is not in classpath.

So, doing:

```
myTemplatesResolver.setCacheable(false);
```

made it work.